# unable to prepare context, unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile Path : c:\.......\.......\

Tags: python, bash, docker, ubuntu, containers

I want to create python image for docker container using ubuntu container

not able because of this

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\Users.....\Desktop.....\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.

what am i doing wrong here is my

dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL maintainer yves 
ADD install.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /install.sh 
RUN /install.sh
ENV PATH C:\Users\....\Desktop\......\dockerfile
CMD ["ipython"]

after i run this command 

docker build -t py4fi:basic

Can someone help me out here!!!! 



Have try all what i read online but now working on this for two days now!!!
```

Comment: What are those dots in the path? Do they represent existing directories?

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux image and has a Linux file system. Your `C:\...` is a Windows path and doesn't make sense in that context.

Comment: (You probably don't need to set `ENV PATH` at all; if you do, its values are directories, and the Dockerfile probably won't exist in the built image at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/` instead of `\` .

Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL maintainer yves 
ADD install.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /install.sh 
RUN /install.sh
ENV PATH C:/Users/..../Desktop/....../dockerfile
# or ENV PATH ./Users/..../Desktop/....../dockerfile
CMD ["ipython"]
```

Comment: try using / instead of \ i got this          /bin/sh: 1: install.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c install.sh /' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Verify if you have a filename as "install.sh" inside of your sh/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working now!!! thanks

i have to download miniconda3 install file then copy in the same folder where i have my dockerfile

Comment: Hi, remember to mark correct answers as "accepted"